# TradingView. How to count how many time an indicator matches a certain criteria?

Tags: pine-script, trading

I have created an indicator. It's more like a statistic, it calculates the maximum difference in the last ex.100 candlesticks.
[image]

I added a line at 10. I need to know: in how many cases the value is bellow and above the line.

How can this be achieved without a loop that runs the script multiple times?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`cum()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_cum):

```
//@version=4
study("")
r = rsi(close, 14)
rAbove = r > 50
rBelow = r <= 50
barsAbove = cum(rAbove ? 1 : 0)
barsBelow = cum(rBelow ? 1 : 0)
plot(barsAbove, "barsAbove")
plot(barsBelow, "barsBelow")
bgcolor(rAbove ? color.green : rBelow ? color.red : na)
plotchar(r, "r", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

without a loop, you'll have to count as you go.
one way could be to count the times your line crossesunder 10.